# Sitecore - Go back to parent bucket

Tags: c#, sitecore, sitecore7

I have a question regarding bucket items in Sitecore.

I have following structure:

[image]

I want to create a button on the 'test' detail page that goes back to the top bucket 'News overview'. Normally I would do something like:

```
LinkManager.GetItemUrl(Sitecore.Context.Item.Parent)
```

The problem here is that the direct parent is the bucket '44' and not 'News overview'. What would be the best way to create a link to the overview bucket?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is an extension method in the Item that gives you the bucket item of your current item.

Its in the `Sitecore.Buckets.Extensions` namespace in the `Sitecore.Buckets.dll` assembly.

You can use it like this:

```
var bucketItem = Sitecore.Context.Item.GetParentBucketItemOrParent();
var urlToBucket = LinkManager.GetItemUrl(bucketItem);
```

You can also use the BucketManager to check if an item is contained within a bucket:

```
BucketManager.IsItemContainedWithinBucket(Sitecore.Context.Item)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could recursively call `[Sitecore.Data.Items.Item].Parent` and perform a check each time until you get to an item with a template id that either is the template ID that you are looking for or is different from the bucket folders' template IDs.

Alternatively, you could also use `[Sitecore.Data.Items.Item].Axes.GetAncestors()`, but this will return you all of the ancestors of the `Item` in top-down order.

Parent/child relationships and methods and techniques for accessing one another did not actually change in Sitecore 7. As such, any techniques that you used in Sitecore 6 should still be usable in Sitecore 7.